# How do I "blur" a selected ComboBox in .net windows forms?

Tags: winforms, combobox

When a ComboBox is clicked this causes it to be selected in the window. Is there a way to perform the equivalent of a javascript blur()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly. You can try focusing the root parent of the combobox or another element, though.

```
comboBox1.TopLevelControl.Focus();
```

or

```
someControl.Focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this similar problem and I managed to fix it by disabling and re-enabling the combobox.

```
comboBox1.Enabled = false;
comboBox1.Enabled = true;
```